# Python - HTML Parsing with Tidy

Tags: python, html-parsing, tidy

This code takes a bit of bad html, uses the Tidy library to clean it up and then passes it to an HtmlLib.Reader().

```
import tidy
options = dict(output_xhtml=1, 
                add_xml_decl=1, 
                indent=1, 
                tidy_mark=0)

from xml.dom.ext.reader import HtmlLib
reader = HtmlLib.Reader()

doc = reader.fromString(tidy.parseString("<Html>Bad Html.", **options))
```

I'm not passing fromString with the right type, it seems, with this Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getComicEmbed.py", line 33, in <module>
    doc = reader.fromString(tidy.parseString("<Html>Bad Html.</b>", **options))
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\_xmlplus\dom\ext\reader\HtmlLib.py", line 67, in fromString
stream = reader.StrStream(str)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\_xmlplus\dom\ext\reader\__init__.py", line 24, in StrStream
return cStringIO.StringIO(st)
TypeError: expected read buffer, _Document found
```

What should I do differently? Thanks!

Comment: Which `tidy` module are you importing?  PyPI shows at least two, and I'm not sure if the one that's included with the `tidy` source distribution (for ubuntu's `tidy` package) is one of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tidy's `parseString` function returns a `_Document` instance which implements `__str__` but not a buffer interface. Therefore `HtmlLib.Reader().fromString` cannot create a `StringIO` object out of it.

This should be fairly simple, change:

```
doc = reader.fromString(tidy.parseString("<Html>Bad Html.", **options))
```

to

```
doc = reader.fromString(str(tidy.parseString("<Html>Bad Html.", **options)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the Python `tidy` module, and am not sure how to find it, but it looks like you need to call something like `toString` on the result of `tidy.fromString` to convert your parsed document back into XHTML.

For a different approach, you could consider using [`lxml.html`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/parsing.html), which is decent at parsing broken markup and provides you with a great ElementTree API for working with the result.  It can also pretty-print *ML, which makes it sort of a superset of tidy, though perhaps not with quite the same ability to navigate incoherent markup.

Also: lxml is written in C (actually, like the python `tidy` module(s), just wraps a C library) so it's much faster than some of the other python modules for working with XML.